# How to get the value of a var within a scope and use it in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get the current logged in users email & save it to a variable on my node/express backend.
Then I want to use that variable in another js file, so I can use it as a mongodb collection. 
Does this only work with a get req & not a post req?

I have tried module.exports, req session passport,

```
//this works, findUser would log the user id
var findUser;
router.get('/dashboard', (req,res)=>{
  findUser = req.user.id;
//findUser = req.session.passport.user;
 console.log(findUser);
res.send(req.user);
});
// this does not work, returns undefined
     users js file
  // module.exports.findUser;
   module.exports.findUser = req.user.id;
    // post.js file
   var sourceFile = require('./users');
   console.log(sourceFile.findUser);
```

I was expecting the var to save across the js files once the user logs in.
Is this an cookie session issue, why is it not possible to create a function just to get the current user, without it being a get req?

Comment: You can't write server code like this.  A node.js server handles request from many different users.  You NEVER store state associated with one specific request outside of the request object itself or some associated session object. To attempt to do so will cause one user's data to get mixed up with another user's data.  The simple programming model is you write a request handler and you do every associated with that request inside that request handler or in functions you call from within that request handler. If you need to pass request state to those other functions, you pass it as arguments.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you want to use a user session.  Read about the express-session module.  You can then write data to the session object and that data will be available to future request handlers when that client makes another request.  That's one way to safely save data on behalf of one particular client that you can use in future requests for that client.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing: `module.exports = req.user.id`. Then, just require it as the same! `const userId = require('./file.js')`.

If you got multiple exports, you can use `module.exports = {id: req.user.id, password: req.user.password}`. When importing, do like that: 

`const user = require('./file.js')
console.log(user.id, user.password)`